# Keyboard type only English (instead Hebrew)

Tags: keyboard

I have issue with my keyboard:
I press Alt+Shift, again and again; from the left-side of the keyboard (below to the 'caps-lock') and from th right-side of keyboard (below to the backspace and enter buttons); Nothing helps!!! It typing only English, instead Hebrew...

Do you have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team-leader give me the best solution...
Restart the computer- and all is O.K

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, go to control panel-region and language/language in windows 8.1 setting and add your language.
I hope it helps you.